# File name changed by Browser on download

Tags: java, firefox

My file download works good, except when certain characters are in the file name.

When I have the following characters in the file name Firefox replaces the characters with an underscore.  Does anyone know why?

The characters that don't work are: `* < > | / : ; ? \ "`

Answer (score 4):

Some of those are not legal characters in certain file systems, like [**NTFS**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#file_and_directory_names), so a file can't be written to with that name. Firefox assumes you'd rather have the file renamed instead of being completely undownloadable.

Comment: I'm on a Windows machine doing the download, would Firefox change the name even though the character is legal on a Windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

Those are special characters reserved by either your filesystem or at least SOME filesystem (not sure how FireFox does it). You likely won't be allowed to create files with these characters in them at all because your Operating System will deny the operation.